# Creating multiple subnets in Azure Terraform using modules

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to deploy two subnets with different ip prefixes and different names and not create too much repeated code. I'm not sure how to approach it best. I tried the below but its not working. My terraform version is 0.14.11 so I think some of what I am doing below might be outdated

My main.tf in root module

```
module "deploy_subnet" {
source              = "./modules/azure_subnet"
subscription_id     = var.subscription_id
resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
region              = var.region
vnet_name           = var.vnet_name
count_subnets       = "${length(var.subnet_prefix)}"
subnet_name         = "${lookup(element(var.subnet_prefix, count.index), "name")}"
address_prefix      = "${lookup(element(var.subnet_prefix, count.index), "ip")}"
}
```

My variables.tf in root module (only pasting relevant part)

```
variable "subnet_prefix" {
type = "list"
default = [
  {
    ip      = "10.0.1.0/24"
    name     = "aks-sn"
  },
  {
    ip      = "10.0.2.0/24"
    name     = "postgres-sn"
  }
]
```

}

My main.tf in my child module folder

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "obc_subnet" {
name = var.subnet_name
count = var.count_subnet
resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
virtual_network_name  = var.vnet_name
address_prefixes      = var.address_prefix
```

}

My variables.tf in my child module folder (only relevant part)

```
variable "subnet_name" {
  description = "Subnet Name"
}
variable "count_subnet" {
  description = "count"
}
variable "address_prefix" {
  description = "IP Address prefix"
}
```

I get the error below

```
Reference to "count" in non-counted context
on main.tf line 8, in module "deploy_subnet":
 8:   subnet_name         = "${lookup(element(var.subnet_prefix, count.index),"name")}"
 The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data"
 blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set

Reference to "count" in non-counted context
on main.tf line 9, in module "deploy_subnet":
9:   address_prefix      = "${lookup(element(var.subnet_prefix, count.index), "ip")}"
The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data"
blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly what it says. In the root module you try to reference a `count.index` but there is nothing being counted. All you do is pass a variable to the child module.

You should just pass `subnet prefix` to the child module, and in the child module set the count to the length of it, and reference `count.index` for the values of `address_prefix` and `name`

Alternatively, and probably more elegant you might look into [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) and each.value